# Is there an user-level accessible font table present in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, fonts

Since there is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437 For MSDOS, is there something similar for Linux systems? Is it possible to access that font data via userland program? I would actually just need an access to the actual bit patterns which define the font, and I would do the rendering myself. I'm fairly sure that *something* like this exists, but I haven't been able to find what exactly is it and how to access it. After all, e.g. text mode console font has to reside somewhere, and I really do hope it is "rawly" accessible *somehow* for a userland program.

Before I forget, I'm programming my program in C, and have access only to the "standard" linux/posix development headers. The only thing I could came up with myself is to use the fonts in /usr/share/fonts, but having to write my own implementations to extract the data from there doesn't sound really an option; I would really want to achieve this with the least amount of bytes possible, so I feel I'm left with finding a standard way of doing this.

It's not really feasible for me to store my own 8x8 ASCII-compatible font with the program either(it takes some 1024 bytes(128 chars * 8x8 bits) just to store the font, which is definitely unacceptable for the strict size limits(some < 1024 bytes for code+data) which I am working with), so being able to use the font data stored at the system itself would greatly simplify my task.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at consolechars sources and it looks like there is a whole library for this kind of stuff. On Ubuntu it's named libconsole and header files (like lct/font.h) are in the console-tools-dev package. There are functions to find and load fonts which seems to be exactly what you need. And consolechars source is a nice example of how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [freetype](http://freetype.org/index2.html) , its commonly installed in all the Linuxes.

Comment: It'll allocate data in program space, thus making it go above his 1024 bytes limit.

Comment: Well there is no other way to do it :-)

Comment: Hmm, seems interesting. I'll need to take a look. Though, I would prefer a "native" way of just accessing some file and reading data directly to a buffer and working with it, rather than doing function calls to libraries since they carry more overhead. But freetype definitely seems the right choice for not-so-size-limited programs, and maybe even for this. Thanks. Edit: Allocating data isn't a problem, bundling it with the program _is_ the problem.

Comment: FWIW Freetype is used on millions of embedded devices, called `Android` :-)

Comment: If allocating data is not a problem (eg: you can use a lot more than 1KB at runtime), you could load any external library you'd like to use at runtime, loading  `dlopen` API...

Comment: Yeah, but using external(dynamically linked) libraries isn't really a problem, they don't increase the object file size apart from the overhead caused by external function calls(which can be compensated with dlopen/dlsymp and function pointers).

Comment: @youngdood Anything you can write yourself will have far far worse performance characteristics than freetype so stop worrying about a couple of function calls. Why are people so obsessed with irrelevant imaginary performance drains. It's not 1963 anymore people!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Although I am somewhat late, I have to comment. This question has/had nothing to do with performance itself. It's/was more about pursue for a small binary size of a program I was writing(1024 bytes) for a certain competition which limits the binary size of the program entries to maximum of 1024 bytes. So not performance, but beating artificial limitations - for fun! ;)